# Can I use my RegularExpression attribute instead of the DataAnnotations one?

Tags: .net, regex, data-annotations

I'm trying to use a reusable regex class and use along with DataAnnotations in MVC.  Something like:

```
[RegularExpressionAttribute1(typeof(MyRegex))]
```

This compiles but no error is thrown if the property doesn't match.

It all works with the standard

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\s*\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$")]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom validation attribute to re-use regular expressions. For email validation you would do something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class EmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public EmailAttribute()
        : base(@"(?i)^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$") { }
}
```