# Ways to share regex across DataAnnotations /Attributes

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I am playing around with the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace, with a view to getting some validation going on my ASP.NET MVC application.

I have already hit an issue with the RegularExpression annotation.

Because these annotations are attributes they require constant expressions.

OK, I can use a class filled with regex string constants.

The problem with that is I don't want to pollute my regex with escape characters required for the C# parser. My preference is to store the regex in a resources file.

The problem is I cant use those string resources in my data annotations, because they are not constants!

Is there any solution to this?

If not, this seems a significant limitation of using attributes for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in .NET 4 there are overrides for the DataAnnotations attribubtes that take a [Func< string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679238%28VS.100%29.aspx) in their constructor described as "The function that enables access to validation resources."

Answer (score 3):

In C# there is only one escape code you need (double-quote)... *if* you use verbatim string literals:

```
@"like \this\ note \slash here does nothing only quote "" needs doubling
you can even use newline";
```

I *always* write regex with `@"..."` strings - avoids many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom validation attribute [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483630/can-i-use-my-regularexpression-attribute-instead-of-the-dataannotations-one/2938695#2938695) as a proxy which would load the regular expressions from your resource file.